# How to code type conversion without modify existing POD types

Tags: c++, boost

In applications of windows, we often use [SYSTEMTIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [FILETIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That's very annoying and verbose to convert them by functions [FileTimeToSystemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SystemTimeToFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724948%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For example,

```
// get the time of now.
SYSTEMTIME stNow;
GetLocalTime(&stNow);

// get the time of 100 seconds later from now.
FILETIME ftNow;
SystemTimeToFileTime(&stNow, &ftNow);
const FILETIME ftLater = get_later_time(ftNow, 100);

// print
SYSTEMTIME stLater;
FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftLater, &stLater);
print_time(stLater);
```

For coding more convenient and cleaner, we can write some conversion functions.

```
FILETIME to_filetime(const SYSTEMTIME &st)
{
    FILETIME ft;
    SystemTimeToFileTime(&st, &ft);
    return ft;
}

SYSTEMTIME to_systemtime(const FILETIME &ft)
{
    SYSTEMTIME st;
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft, &st);
    return st;
}
```

The annoying codes can be rewritten cleaner.

```
// get the time of now.
SYSTEMTIME stNow;
GetLocalTime(&stNow);

// print the time of 100 seconds later from now
print_time(to_systemtime(get_later_time(to_filetime(stNow), 100)));
```

My question is there other methods to make them convertible? For example, how could I extend  the conversion to `boost::lexical_cast`,

```
FILETIME ftNow = boost::lexical_cast<FILETIME>(stNow);
SYSTEMTIME stNow2 = boost::lexical_cast<SYSTEMTIME>(ftNow);
```

Or is possible (I think no) to overload conversion operator?

```
FILETIME ftNow = stNow;
SYSTEMTIME stNow2 = ftNow;
```

Comment: In what way `boost::lexical_cast<FILETIME>(stNow)` is more convenient than `SystemTimeToFileTime(stNow)`?

Comment: @n.m. You have to write more code/line if `SystemTimeToFileTime`, and it's not possible to make `FIMETILE` the result of `SystemTimeToFileTime` been const.

Comment: Oh sorry. I meant to ask, how `boost::lexical_cast<FILETIME>(stNow)` is more convenient than `to_filetime(stNow)`?

Comment: Yes for me, `to_filetime` is a new name. for development, I prefer to remember less the better.

Comment: `boost::lexical_cast` does not belong here at all. It is for converting between things and their lexical forms (i.e. strings), so readers familiar with `boost::lexical_cast` will be surprised. `to_filetime` does what anyone would expect it to do. Following the principle of least surprise, we must reject `lexical_cast`.

Comment: Well, I think I misused `lexical_cast`, thanks.

Comment: I would write my own conversion template and call it `windows_cast` :^P

Answer (score 0):

One method is to create a class for storing time, with conversions to and from `FILETIME` and `SYSTEMTIME`, and use it exclusively. You can base it on a union of. `FILETIME` and `SYSTEMTIME`. The following is untested.

```
class WinTime {
    bool isSystem;
    union {
        SYSTEMTIME sys;
        FILETIME fil;
     };
  public:
    // Implementing these is trivial
    WinTime (const FILETIME&);
    WinTime (const SYSTEMTIME&);
    WinTime (const WinTime&);
    operator FILETIME() const;
    operator SYSTEMTIME() const;

    // add these if you want to use it in WinApi
    WinTime(){}
    FILETIME* asFiletime() { isSystem = false; return &fil; }
    SYSTEMTIME* asSystemtime() { isSystem = true; return &sys; }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had created this before :p